# SQL Server 2012 - Unique Priority Column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, triggers

I have a table of Tasks, with a priority column (int); the column has a unique filtered index for all Non-Null values.
Currently I have a Trigger to give all new records a Priority of Max([Priority])+1, and whenever an item is marked as completed it changes the Priority to Null and decrements all values greater than the Priority of the completed task by one.

The Problem occurs when I try to add the ability to Re-prioritize, I created a procedure to run before an Update that increments / decrements all priorities between the old and new Value. The problem is that the trigger never fires because I get a unique constraint violation when I try to change any value.

But the trigger works perfectly if I remove the unique constraint on the index. Is there any way i can make this work while keeping the unique constraint on my index?

```
ALTER TRIGGER [Schema].[TR_UpdatePriority] 
   ON  [Schema].[TableName] 
   FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE(Priority)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @NEWP int, @OLDP int, @MAXP int;
        SET @NEWP = (SELECT Priority FROM inserted);
        SET @OLDP = (SELECT Priority FROM deleted);
        SET @MAXP = (Select MAX(Priority) FROM Schema.TableName) + 1;
        IF (@NEWP > @MAXP) SET @NEWP = @MAXP;
        IF (@NEWP is NULL ) -- if priority changed to NULL (Complete / Deleted)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE T 
                SET T.Priority = T.Priority - 1 
                FROM Schema.TableName as T LEFT JOIN inserted ON T.ID = inserted.ID
                WHERE inserted.ID is null AND T.Priority >= @OLDP;
        END
        ELSE IF (@OLDP is NULL) -- if priority changed From NULL
        BEGIN
            UPDATE T 
                SET T.Priority = T.Priority + 1 
                FROM Schema.TableName as T LEFT JOIN inserted ON T.ID = inserted.ID
                WHERE inserted.ID is null AND T.Priority >= @NEWP;
        END
        ELSE IF (@NEWP > @OLDP) -- if priority Increased
        BEGIN
            UPDATE T 
                SET T.Priority = T.Priority - 1 
                FROM Schema.TableName as T LEFT JOIN inserted ON T.ID = inserted.ID
                WHERE inserted.ID is null AND T.Priority <= @NEWP AND T.Priority > @OLDP;

        END
        ELSE IF (@NEWP < @OLDP) -- if priority Decreased
        BEGIN
            UPDATE T 
                SET T.Priority = T.Priority + 1 
                FROM Schema.TableName as T LEFT JOIN inserted ON T.ID = inserted.ID
                WHERE inserted.ID is null AND T.Priority >= @NEWP AND T.Priority < @OLDP;
        END
    END
END
```

And before anyone else says it I know the Begin / End between each item in the IF / ELSE IF statement is not needed, but I just like formatting it that way.

Comment: As a note:  I definitely have no complaint about the use of `BEGIN`/`END`.  I think it is a good programming habit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a temporary table that will have the following structure:

```
#tempPriority(ID | OldPriority | NewPriority)
```

The flow in the trigger, for the "tricky" scenarios, would be something like:
- Begin transaction
- Insert data into temporary table (old priorities and new ones)
- NULL all Priority values
- Update destination table with join to the temporary table and set the NewPriority (set the correct values from the temporary tables
- End transaction if all went good

Comment: This approach works, but it seems like too much extra manipulation of the table. Plus it takes about 10 times as long as my old method, which isn't a good thing. I was considering just removing the unique constraint on the Index, as the only way I know of to generate duplicate items in this field is through batch changes, regular users will only be editing one record at a time. i could just create a ne stored procedure to scan through the field at some interval and make sure the priority field is unique and contiguous.

Comment: @Ryan Hoover, I was thinking of that. I guess minor improvement would be to filter the rows that already have NULL on the Priority column. If you are taking the drop constraint - update - re-add constraint approach make sure you have an error handling mechanism in place (to ensure you reinforce the constraint if something fails).